# The position of the macula in comparison to the blind spot

Tags: human-anatomy, eyes, anatomy, human-eye

Which is located in a higher postion? Macula or blind spot?

Comment: The first image is a section of the eye. What was the plane of this section: longitudinal, transverse, or something else? Also, for the second image, what was the orientation of the camera? Are these images of the right eye or the left eye? Thinking along these lines will lead you to the answer.

Comment: @Adhish The first image is a section of the left eye and the second one is also of the left eye. Can we say that macula and blind spot are almost in the same positon or level (horizontal)